about scss variable references?
I have three files: a.scss,b.scss,c.scss;
The relationship between these three files:
c @use b as *
b @use a as *
"a.scss" have variable color
Can I reference "color" in a in c.scss
I try to reference the variable "color" in c:
background-color:$color

, but I get an error:variable undefine

By default, styles imported with @use in file b are only visible there; they do not carry over to file c that @uses file b. To allow them to carry over, you can use the @forward rule in file b: @forward "src/a";
